# Group list of objects based on date(hourly)

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have a list of `Objects` with `java.util.date` as one of the fields. How to separate/filter `Objects` based on date(hourly). I.e For example: `Objects` with a date range from 12.00 to 13:00 should be separated or form a new list and so on for every hour. Help me achieve this.

Comment: You can first sort according to date and then group them one by one. (You should give a more detailed description of your question and if possible post your code)

Comment: @zhh Thanks for the idea. Perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stream your original list of objects, and then use the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collector.

This will give you a `Map` where the keys are the hours, and the values are list of object for that hour.

```
List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();

Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> objectsPerHour = objects.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getHour));
```

I assumed an implementation of `MyObject` like this (you can implement `getHour()` like you want):

```
class MyObject {

    private Date date;

    public int getHour() {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).getHour();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Ward. My requirement is for every half-an-hour. I have code accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
List<MyClass> yourFinalList = list.stream().filter(x -> Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(x.getDate())) >= 12 && Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(x.getDate())) <= 13).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(yourFinalList.size());
```

Hope your class is like below:

```
public class MyClass {
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    Date date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DateComparator implements Comparator<XYZ> {
    public int compare(XYZ obj1, XYZ obj2) {
        if (obj1.getDate().before(obj2.getDate()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (obj1.getDate().after(obj2.getDate()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not null safe and also does not really answer the question